# LINQ: Use .Except() on collections of different types by making them convertible/comparable?

Tags: c#, linq, comparison, equality, comparable

Given two lists of different types, is it possible to make those types convertible between or comparable to each other (eg with a TypeConverter or similar) so that a LINQ query can compare them?  I've seen other similar questions on SO but nothing that points to making the types convertible between each other to solve the problem.

Collection Types:

```
public class Data
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    private Data _data;

    public ViewModel(Data data)
    {
        _data = data;
    }
}
```

Desired usage:

```
    public void DoMerge(ObservableCollection<ViewModel> destination, IEnumerable<Data> data)
    {
        // 1. Find items in data that don't already exist in destination
        var newData = destination.Except(data);

        // ...
    }
```

It would seem logical that since I know how to compare an instance of ViewModel to an instance of Data I should be able to provide some comparison logic that LINQ would then use for queries like .Except().  Is this possible?

Comment: Poor old `for` loop, he was once so useful but, alas, he never makes the one-liner people happy.

Comment: @Marc: I don't agree with the sentiment you are expressing. We have ways of writing code now that more clearly expresses the intent without worrying about the mechanism. `for` expresses mechanisms and obscures intent. The LINQ-based one-liners that you are decrying often (yes, not always) better express intent and hide mechanisms. This leads to code that is easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: @Jason, while I was being flippant, any functions you throw into a projection like you are only provides an assumption of intent.

Comment: @Jason, simply that I agree when the LINQ hides simple control-structure based logic. A projection from one type to another is not one of those cases, imo.  It's no more clear what is happening than in `var newData = MeaningfulFunctionNameHere(destination, data);` In both cases, we make an assumption about what is really happening. In reality, I was really just poking fun at the LINQ is cool and applies everywhere crowd.

Comment: What's wrong with you? LINQ *is* cool and does apply everywhere. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to provide a projection from `Data` to `ViewModel` so that you can say

```
var newData = destination.Except(data.Select(x => f(x)));
```

where `f` maps `Data` to `ViewModel`. You will need a `IEqualityComparer<Data>` too.

Answer (score 10):

I know this is late but there is a simpler syntax using Func that eliminates the need for a comparer.

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
   public static IEnumerable<TSource> Except<TSource, VSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<VSource> second, Func<TSource, VSource, bool> comparer)
   {
       return first.Where(x => second.Count(y => comparer(x, y)) == 0);
   }

   public static IEnumerable<TSource> Contains<TSource, VSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<VSource> second, Func<TSource, VSource, bool> comparer)
   {
       return first.Where(x => second.FirstOrDefault(y => comparer(x, y)) != null);
   }

   public static IEnumerable<TSource> Intersect<TSource, VSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<VSource> second, Func<TSource, VSource, bool> comparer)
   {
       return first.Where(x => second.Count(y => comparer(x, y)) == 1);
   }
}
```

so with lists of class Foo and Bar

```
public class Bar
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string OtherBar { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string OtherFoo { get; set; }
}
```

one can run Linq statements like

```
var fooExceptBar = fooList.Except(barList, (f, b) => f.Id == b.Id);
var barExceptFoo = barList.Except(fooList, (b, f) => b.OtherBar == f.OtherFoo);
```

it's basically a slight variation on above but seems cleaner to me.

Comment: i like this solution

Comment: Nice solution.  As an optimisation I'd recommend replacing .Count() with .Any() to avoid unnecessary iteration over the collection.

Comment: Nice! Another suggestion: replace `null` by `default(VSource)`

Answer (score 7):

I assume that providing a projection from `Data` to `ViewModel` is problematic, so I'm offering another solution in addition to Jason's.

Except uses a hash set (if I recall correctly), so you can get similar performance by creating your own hashset.  I'm also assuming that you are identifying `Data` objects as equal when their `IDs` are equal.

```
var oldIDs = new HashSet<int>(data.Select(d => d.ID));
var newData = destination.Where(vm => !oldIDs.Contains(vm.Data.ID));
```

You might have another use for a collection of "oldData" elsewhere in the method, in which case, you would want to do this instead.  Either implement `IEquatable<Data>` on your data class, or create a custom `IEqualityComparer<Data>` for the hash set:

```
var oldData = new HashSet<Data>(data);
//or: var oldData = new HashSet<Data>(data, new DataEqualityComparer());
var newData = destination.Where(vm => !oldData.Contains(vm.Data));
```

Comment: Why would it be problematic? `ViewModel` has a constructor that takes `Data`!

Comment: I mean "problematic" for performance, or philosophically, not in terms of figuring out how to write the code. Performance-wise, the `ViewModel` class might require a lot of other overhead in its construction.  Philosophically, it seems odd to create a bunch of objects just so we can use `Except` to select some objects that don't meet certain criteria.

Answer (score 5):

If you use this :

```
var newData = destination.Except(data.Select(x => f(x)));
```

You have to project 'data' to same type contained in 'destination', but using the code below you could get rid of this limitation :

```
//Here is how you can compare two different sets.
class A { public string Bar { get; set; } }
class B { public string Foo { get; set; } }

IEnumerable<A> setOfA = new A[] { /*...*/ };
IEnumerable<B> setOfB = new B[] { /*...*/ };
var subSetOfA1 = setOfA.Except(setOfB, a => a.Bar, b => b.Foo);

//alternatively you can do it with a custom EqualityComparer, if your not case sensitive for instance.
var subSetOfA2 = setOfA.Except(setOfB, a => a.Bar, b => b.Foo, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

//Here is the extension class definition allowing you to use the code above
public static class IEnumerableExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<TFirst> Except<TFirst, TSecond, TCompared>(
        this IEnumerable<TFirst> first,
        IEnumerable<TSecond> second,
        Func<TFirst, TCompared> firstSelect,
        Func<TSecond, TCompared> secondSelect)
    {
        return Except(first, second, firstSelect, secondSelect, EqualityComparer<TCompared>.Default);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TFirst> Except<TFirst, TSecond, TCompared>(
        this IEnumerable<TFirst> first,
        IEnumerable<TSecond> second,
        Func<TFirst, TCompared> firstSelect,
        Func<TSecond, TCompared> secondSelect,
        IEqualityComparer<TCompared> comparer)
    {
        if (first == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("first");
        if (second == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("second");
        return ExceptIterator<TFirst, TSecond, TCompared>(first, second, firstSelect, secondSelect, comparer);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<TFirst> ExceptIterator<TFirst, TSecond, TCompared>(
        IEnumerable<TFirst> first,
        IEnumerable<TSecond> second,
        Func<TFirst, TCompared> firstSelect,
        Func<TSecond, TCompared> secondSelect,
        IEqualityComparer<TCompared> comparer)
    {
        HashSet<TCompared> set = new HashSet<TCompared>(second.Select(secondSelect), comparer);
        foreach (TFirst tSource1 in first)
            if (set.Add(firstSelect(tSource1)))
                yield return tSource1;
    }
}
```

Some may argue that's memory inefficient due to the use of an HashSet. But actually the Enumerable.Except method of the framework is doing the same with a similar internal class called 'Set' (I took a look by decompiling).

Answer (score 0):

Dirty trick: project the two lists to just their shared IDs, do the `Except`, and then project the resulting list again to the original type using a `Join` with the original list to add the rest of the properties you removed with the first `Select`.
Probably the performance is not great, but for small lists it will be okay.

```
listOfType1.Select(x => x.Id)
    .Except(listOfType2.Select(x => x.Id))
    .Join(listOfType1,
        onlyIds => onlyIds,
        fullData => fullData.Id,
        (onlyIds, fullData)
        => new Type1
        {
            Id = fullData.Id,
            OtherPropertyOfType1 = fullData.OtherPropertyOfType1
        });
```